# How do I add a d-bus command as a global shortcut in Gnome (classic)?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

How do I add a d-bus command as a global shortcut in Gnome (classic)? I can do it in KDE, it gives an option to add a new shortcut as a d-bus command. I do not want to write a script just for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, found it. Use qdbus as the command line interface:

```
qdbus <Remote Application> <Remote object> <Function>
```

I was trying to control spotify. The playPause command would be :

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

Comment: dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause if we are in Gnome-Shell